# Create React App(npm run build) generates chunk.js file with unwanted content of package.json

Tags: javascript, security, webpack, create-react-app, package.json

I have a security issue with that because my `*.chunk.js` file contains content of `package.json` file + expected `js` code of course. How i can get rid of that `package.json` content?

I'm running default set of CRA2 with

```
"build-js": "react-scripts build",
"build": "npm-run-all build-js"
```

Comment: What content are you getting when you run the script npm run build-js which internally run react scripts build ?

Comment: SOLVED - there was an import of `package.json` in `App.js` to get the version of an app

Comment: cool, i have added the comment as the answer kindly check :)

Answer (score -1):

As discussed on the comments the issue was import of package.json on the App.js file.

So while building it has added the package.json file data on the chunk.js

Removing the import of package.json  solved the issue.